# How to make SwiftUI's NavigationSplitView retain State for detail views?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way in SwiftUI to make a `NavigationSplitView` retain the `State` for its detail views when switching between them? To reproduce the issue with this example, switch to pane 2, scroll down, switch to pane 1, switch back to pane 2, and see that pane 2 has lost it's scroll position. ScrollPosition is just one example of lost State. Text selections with `.textSelection(.enabled)` are lost. List filters that I track in State are lost. In comparison `TabView` doesn't none of these issue. I'm testing on Mac Catalyst, macOS 13.6. Apple's [Food Truck example app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/food_truck_building_a_swiftui_multiplatform_app) also has this issue.

```
import SwiftUI

enum Panel: Hashable {
    case one
    case two
}

struct BigList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1...500, id: \.self) { value in
                Text("\(value)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailColumn: View {
    @Binding var selection: Panel?
    
    var body: some View {
        switch selection ?? .one {
        case .one:
            BigList()
        case .two:
            BigList()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestSplitViewApp: App {
    @State private var selection: Panel? = Panel.one
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List(selection: $selection) {
                    NavigationLink(value: Panel.one) {
                        Label("One", systemImage: "circle")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(value: Panel.two) {
                        Label("Two", systemImage: "circle")
                    }
                }
            } detail: {
                NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                    DetailColumn(selection:$selection)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selection) { _ in
                path.removeLast(path.count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could capture the position of a `ScrollView` yourself and restore it when returning to the view. If your deployment target is iOS 17 / macOS 14 then `scrollPosition` could be used for this. But since you're using macOS 13.6, you might need to use a `ScrollViewReader`.

Comment: Thank you, yes I could do that, but that will only help with one part of the State that is lost. It would also mean the view needs to be rebuilt and underlying queries rerun which would be unnecessarily slow.

Comment: Just move state up in the hierarchy

Comment: Thank you - That sounds challenging to almost impossible - would I have to literally move all of the state in the whole app to the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch panels, the previously displayed `BigList` is *removed entirely* from the view hierarchy, because that `switch` case is not reached during the view update, and a *brand new* `BigList` is created.

This is why the scroll position is not maintained. Every time you switch to a panel, you are seeing a brand new `BigList`.

To maintain the scroll position, you would need to prevent SwiftUI from removing the `BigList`s. Both of them need to be in memory. You can put them in a `ZStack`, and use `opacity` to control which is visible:

```
ZStack {
    BigList()
        .opacity(selection == .two ? 1 : 0)
    BigList()
        .opacity(selection != .two ? 1 : 0)
}
```

However, this will also remove the "scroll edge" appearance of the navigation bar (because the root of the navigation destination is not a `List` anymore). You either need to use `.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)` to keep the navigation bar always visible, or let the list overlap with the transparent navigation bar.

---

Alternatively, `DetailColumn` can store the scroll position for both panels in `@State`s, but this is more involved. See here for a starting point: [Tracking scroll position in a List SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74047146/tracking-scroll-position-in-a-list-swiftui)