# Recover ScrollView content position

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Is there some way to recover `ScrollView` content position without visual "jumps"? (for example to set ScrollView content offset before it will be rendered). I mean exact content position last time before disappearing/deallocating of `ScrollView`. Somehow to save and recover `ScrollView` state and provide the same position which user saw it last time.

I tried some ways to measure content offset with `GeometryReader` and recover with `ScrollViewProxy.scrollTo()`, but it is not safe and can cause runtime errors and crashes according to Apple documentation:

> You may not use the ScrollViewProxy during execution of the content view builder; doing so results in a runtime error

```swift
struct Screen : View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            background
            VStack {
                frontWindow
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var frontWindow: some View { FrontWindow() }
    
    private var background: some View { Color.black }
    
}

private struct FrontWindow : View {
    
    @State private var expanded = true
    @State private var items: [Int] = (0..<200000).map { $0 }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack { Spacer(); button; Spacer() }
            if expanded { list }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
    }
    
    private var button: some View {
        Button { withAnimation { expanded.toggle() } } label: {
            HStack { 
                Spacer()
                Text(expanded ? "hide" : "expand")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var list: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    HStack { Spacer(); Text("\(item)"); Spacer() }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: To avoid crashes, perform `scrollTo` in `.onAppear`. See also [How to make SwiftUI's NavigationSplitView retain State for detail views?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77968171/20386264)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `iOS 17+` new scroll APIs to keep track of the content offset based on list values. First, declare a `@State` variable like so:

```
@State private var activeID: Int?
```

I'm using an Int because you are using `Int` for your items, but you can use any object conforming to `Hashable`.

Then, modify your **list View** to use the new API's:

```
private var list: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                HStack { Spacer(); Text("\(item)"); Spacer() }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        /// This is mandatory in order to keep track of scroll content changes
        .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
    .scrollPosition(id: $activeID, anchor: .center)
    .onAppear {
        /// Set list content position here based on the value
        activeID = items.count/2
    }
    /// Keep track of any scroll
    .onChange(of: activeID) { oldValue, newValue in
        print("New Active ID: \(newValue ?? 0)")
    }
}
```

What's new here is the `scrollTargetLayout` and `scrollPosition` modifiers. The first one tells what is the content that you want to keep track of, and the second one updates the current position based on the view `scrollTargetLayout` is attached to.

Since you also want the app to reload its last position of the ScrollView you can use the `AppStorage` **property wrapper** to save it:

```
@AppStorage("activeID") private var savedActiveID: Int?
```

and update the `onAppear` and add the `onDisappear` too:

```
.onAppear {
    /// Set list content position here based on the value
    activeID = savedActiveID ?? items.count/2
}
.onDisappear {
    savedActiveID = activeID ?? 0
}
```

And if you want to cover all cases maybe it is even better to use the `scenePhase`. First declare the **scene phase** in the View:

```
@Environment(\.scenePhase) private var phase
```

Then use the `onChange` to observe changes of the scene (app goes to background, etc...):

```
.onChange(of: phase) { oldValue, newValue in
        switch newValue {
        case .background:
            return
        case .inactive:
            savedActiveID = activeID ?? 0
        case .active:
            return
        @unknown default:
            return
        }
    }
```

Hope you find this solution useful.
Let me know if this could work for you!

Comment: thank you for this solution, but i need something for minimum deployment target iOS 15.0